# Showing that $\langle f(x), N(s)\rangle = -p(s)$ where $f$ is a biregular curve and $p = 1/k$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $f: I \subset \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a  curve parametrized by arclength. We assume that $f$ is biregular, that the torsion $\tau$ doesn't vanish and we put $p = 1/k$ and $\sigma = 1/\tau$.

> Show that for every $s \in I, \langle f(s), N(s)\rangle = -p(s)$.

($N$ is the normal unit vector)

I am stuck at this question. 
What I did was:
$$\langle f(s), N(s)\rangle = \langle f(s), \frac{f''(s)}{\|f''(s)\|}\rangle =  $$
$$\frac{\langle f(s), f''(s)\rangle }{k(s)} $$

And I have no clue how to proceed now.

Comment: What does "biregular" mean in this context?

Comment: @RobertLewis Biregular means that $\forall s \in I, f''(s) \not = 0$

Comment: Are you sure you don' want $\langle f'(s), N(s) \rangle = -p$?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that is right either!

Comment: @RobertLewis Will have to ask my teacher. I was unable to prove it.

Comment: Indeed, @RobertLewis, that dot product is always $0$. ... JohnMayne, it's very false in general — try a circular helix.

Answer (score 1):

The set-up of the exercise reminds me of a standard exercise about arclength-parametrized curves on a sphere centered at the origin.

Assume that $\|f(s)\|=\text{constant}$ and then you should be able to prove this. Square this equality and differentiate twice.